# Cannot manage users in PWA. ArgumentNullException at BuildCFInputRow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server, pwa

Everything else seems to be working fine, but we cannot add new PWA users and we cannot click on any existing ones without getting an error.

What we are doing to reproduce it:

- PWA Settings
- Manage Users
- New User
- OR:
- Clicking on any user

URL of the page with an error: `/PWA/_layouts/15/PWA/Admin/AddModifyUser.aspx`

[image]

Error in the ULS:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: format   
 at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, NULL , Object[] args)   
Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.CustomFieldUtil.BuildCFInputRow(Control ctlParent, CustomFieldsRow cf, String cfID, Hashtable htValues, ArrayList clientIdAl, ArrayList divBtnPairs, Boolean useSecondaryUid, Boolean fieldReadOnly, Boolean isBulkEdit, String currency, Boolean loadDefaultForLU, Boolean forceSingleValue, LookupTableDataSet ltds, Nullable`1 serverSeparator, Page page, PJContext pjContext, Boolean& bShouldSetDirty) 
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.CustomFieldUtil.BuildCFInputRow(Control ctlParent, CustomFieldsRow cf, String cfID, Hashtable htValues, ArrayList clientIdAl, ArrayList divBtnPairs, Boolean useSecondaryUid, Boolean fieldReadOnly, Boolean isBulkEdit, String currency, Boolean loadDefaultForLU, Boolean forceSingleValue, LookupTableDataSet ltds, Nullable`1 serverSeparator, Page page, PJContext pjContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.CustomFieldUtil.BuildBuiltInCFRow(CustomFieldsRow cf, CFInfo inf, PJBasePage page, HtmlControl idFieldDiv, DataRow[] cfValues, Boolean isBulkEdit, BuiltInType thisBuiltInType, String thisFieldId, String currency, Boolean loadLUDefaults, Boolean forceSingleValue, LookupTableDataSet ltDS, Nullable`1 serverListSeparator, PJContext pjContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.CustomFieldUtil.BuildResourceBuiltInCFRow(CustomFieldsRow cfRow, CFInfo inf, PJBasePage page, HtmlControl idFieldDiv, DataRow[] cfValues, Boolean isBulkEdit, BuiltInType thisBuiltInType, String fieldId, String currency, Boolean loadLUDefaults, LookupTableDataSet ltDS, Nullable`1 serverListSeparator, PJContext pjContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.CustomFieldUtil.BuildResourceBuiltInCFRow(CustomFieldsRow cfRow, CFInfo inf, PJBasePage page, HtmlControl idFieldDiv, DataRow[] cfValues, Boolean isBulkEdit, BuiltInType thisBuiltInType, String currency, Boolean loadLUDefaults, LookupTableDataSet ltDS, Nullable`1 serverListSeparator, PJContext pjContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.ApplicationPages.AddModifyUserPage.BindResource()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.ApplicationPages.AddModifyUserPage.InitGlobals()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.ApplicationPages.AddModifyUserPage.PJWebPage_OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.PJWebPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

**Update**
The issue disappeared for about 15 minutes. But now it's back. I can't find any correlation or explanation yet.

**Farm Topology**
2 WFEs and 2 App servers. All four of these have PWA service enabled.

Things I've tried:

- Cleared SharePoint farm cache on all servers.
- Disabled PWA Service on the server that had an error according to ULS. The error still occurs, just on the other server this time.

Comment: The `ui-ui` message is normal. But has the farm been patched recently? What patch level is the farm at?

Comment: It's 15.0.4937 - ​June 2017 CU. There were no updates installed in the last 6-8 months. I've figured that ui-ui message was happening because SharePoint didn't recognize Canadian English. When I switched the browser language to en-us - this message went away, but fixed nothing.

Comment: I'm guessing that the AddModifyUser.aspx page has a bug. Method PWA.CustomFieldUtil.BuildCFInputRow(...) tries to render an ASP.net input  control and probably fails to format the value for the number input or a calendar input. For some reason "format" parameter is null.  I wonder if it has something to do with the languages.